# Why or when would you set SET XACT_ABORT to OFF?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know what `XACT_ABORT` is. There is a lot of info on why to set this to `on`. My question is why would someone set it to `off`? The point of a transaction is either everything is done or nothing is done. So why would someone set this to `off`? Why MS even choose `off` as the default is strange (The default for triggers is `on` and I know that).

Comment: Much functionality exists for historical reasons. Why is the "+" operator used for both string concatenation and addition arithmetic? Why does implicit conversion exist? But I suggest you read Erland's discussion of [error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). It is off by default - people don't generally set it off on purpose AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I can only think of one decent reason as to why you would. That would be that you would want the transaction to continue processing regardless of any errors that are flagged. It might be that you want to deal with the errors later on rather than having the entire transaction rolled back.

There are also certain times when having XACT_ABORT isn't required for data modification statements but requirement is different to preference.

Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)